# Microsoft Test manager and Test Foundation server

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

We looking to set up new Testing tool to manage test cases,defects and daily executions so few of my dev project manager forcing to keep TFS only [ as part of cost saving and also they already purchased VS professional which does not come with MTM addon] so we testing team would like to go For MTM which is more advance as compare to only TFS for test managing purpose. so anyone would help me to know about the whats exactly benefits of MTM over TFS. i have searched many sites all they talked about MTM only none of sites mentioned about the different between this two. please let me know some advantages so it will help me and my company to adopt new testing tool for new team , cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's hardly to compare Test Manager and Test Foundation server. Cause there is no Test Foundation server, even you google it, you can only get the result related to Team Foundation server.

Team Foundation server is a Application Lifecycle Management. Which including much more than test, such as version control, build, work-item, release management...

For MTM, we usually use Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) to help you test the application you built. MTM stores your test plans and results on Team Foundation Server (TFS).

If you mean the test in visual studio, please refer this two links in MSDN to compare both: [Testing your application using Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635157.aspx) ***VS*** [System testing your application using Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620889.aspx)